# Magento 2 Paypal express checkout error on checkout page

Tags: magento2, paypal

I'm using magento 2.0.7 , and yesterday my website start to have a strange issue , without any change. Basicly I have 2 payment gateway options , one is for cc and it works fine , the other one is paypal express checkout , and it was working fint till yesterday. Now , when I go on the checkout page , and press the "Pay with Paypal" button , I get an error saying:

> You will be redirected to the PayPal website.

And if I press it while inspecting the page, I get this error:

> jquery.js:9666 PUT https://xxxxxx.xx/rest/default/V1/guest-carts/c4f575f8d139addc9bc11795acaf25fe/selected-payment-method 501 (Method Not Implemented)

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be from browser, it happens on some environments ( good to go with error logs once ).

Try this

1. Try clearing your cookies and your cache (bin/magento cache:clean && bin/magento cache:flush)
2. Type about:config into the URL bar, list of configuration settings for Firefox
3. Locate the setting for 'network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris'
4. Set the value of names of the servers to use NTLM with.
5. Locate the setting for 'network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris'
6. Set the value of names of the servers to use NTLM with.
7. network.automatic-ntlm-auth.allow-proxies = True
8. Restart Firefox - Test URL to application.

Comment: I've just tryed to do so, and I get the same error.. any other suggestion ?